# What is Dissipative Control?

Tags: control-engineering, pid-control

I am reading an [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212212.pdf) that says:

> stabilize the multi-vehicle system to one of its local minima via dissipative control

And [other](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6000456) that deals with dissipative system:

> (PID) controllers is designed to make the closed-loop linear system asymptotically stable and strictly quadratic dissipative

**Question**: What exactly is dissipative control or quadratic dissipative?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissipative_system, quadratic refers to the storage function, thus dissaptive for a quadratic storage function, e.g. x^T P x

Comment: thanks but as usual, wikipedia is not that intuitive. What exactly is dissipative control?

Comment: a controller such that the system is disspative, thus the "energy" in the system does increase faster than the supply rate.

Comment: I see, makes sense. Any example of such controller?

Comment: e.g. a P-controller that stabilizes a linear first-order system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intuitive idea is that a dissipative system cannot store more energy than what was initially stored plus what is supplied during an experiment, which is schematically depicted below.
[image: Visualization of dissipativity]
This figure is adopted from: http://www.eeci-institute.eu/pdf/M012/lec2.pdf

So we write that a system $\dot{x} = f(x,u)$, $y = g(x,u)$ is dissipative with respect to the supply rate $s(u,y)$ if there exists a storage function $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ such that the dissipation inequality
$$V\big(x(t_1)\big) \leq V\big(x(t_0)\big) + \int_{t_0}^{t_1} s\big(u(t),y(t)\big) \;\mathrm{d}t$$
hold for all system trajectories and for all $t_0< t_1$.

We call it quadratic dissipative if the storage function is a quadratic function, e.g. $V(x) = x^\top P x$.

Thus dissipative control is a controller such that the closed-loop system is dissipative with respect to the in- and output of the closed loop system.

Comment: Well the visuals make it more understandable. Thanks